# Firebase remote config crashing (objective c iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am having trouble fetching information from Firebase RemoteConfig. On app install, I have a language selection screen before the MainController view controller. On the MainController View controller, I am doing a RemoteConfig fetch. It works the first time, when the language selection screen is shown before the MainController view controller. But, from the next time, it crashes on this particular line:

```
[self.remoteConfig fetchWithExpirationDuration:expirationDuration completionHandler:^(FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatus status, NSError *error) {
```

With the following exception:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString firstObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0000000000616a2'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d20134b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cc6221e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d270f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d186c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d186798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   English                             0x0000000107f44e1b -[GIPLocale googleLanguageWithAppleLanguages:] + 33
    6   English                             0x0000000107f45396 -[GIPLocale recalculateLocale] + 54
    7   English                             0x0000000107f44c26 -[GIPLocale initWithLanguageMappings:] + 99
    8   English                             0x0000000107f44b77 __25+[GIPLocale googleLocale]_block_invoke + 41
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010da900cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010da751fc dispatch_once_f + 501
    11  English                             0x0000000107f44b4c +[GIPLocale googleLocale] + 42
    12  English                             0x0000000107f42d06 +[RCNDevice deviceLocale] + 31
    13  English                             0x0000000107f43344 +[RCNDevice hasDeviceContextChanged:projectIdentifier:] + 325
    14  English                             0x0000000107f3e133 -[RCNConfigFetch fetchAllConfigsWithExpirationDuration:completionHandler:] + 150
    15  English                             0x0000000107f3577f -[FIRRemoteConfig fetchWithExpirationDuration:completionHandler:] + 77
```

**UPDATE:** It doesn't matter if I show the language selection screen or not. It always works on a fresh install and stops working from next launches.

This is my full code I am using.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //Display select language settings
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:DISPLAY_LANGUAGE_SETTING])
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults  setBool:TRUE forKey:DISPLAY_LANGUAGE_SETTING];
        [defaults synchronize];
        //Display Language Screen
        AGSelectLanguageViewController *languageViewController =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AGSelectLanguageViewController"];
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self presentViewController:languageViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

  [self configFireBase];

}
  -(void)configFireBase{
        // Firebase Configuration
        self.remoteConfig = [FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig];
       //Enabling development mode
        FIRRemoteConfigSettings *remoteConfigSettings = [[FIRRemoteConfigSettings alloc] initWithDeveloperModeEnabled:YES];
        self.remoteConfig.configSettings = remoteConfigSettings;

        //Set default Remote Config values
        [self.remoteConfig setDefaultsFromPlistFileName:@"RemoteConfigDefaults"];

        [self fetchConfig];
    }

- (void)fetchConfig {
    _discount_percentage = self.remoteConfig[DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE].numberValue.floatValue;

    long expirationDuration = 3600;

    if (self.remoteConfig.configSettings.isDeveloperModeEnabled) {
        expirationDuration = 0;
    }


    [self.remoteConfig fetchWithExpirationDuration:expirationDuration completionHandler:^(FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatus status, NSError *error) {
        if (status == FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatusSuccess) {
            NSLog(@"Config fetched!");
            [self.remoteConfig activateFetched];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Config not fetched");
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

Where am I wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GIPLocale class does some mapping between Google and Apple names for locales, and as part of that it pulls the app's locales from NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

I am guessing that somewhere that defaults entry is getting set to just a string or similar rather than an array - check if you're referencing that string anywhere in your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I was inserting this value in AppleLanguages -   
[defaults setObject:[localeList objectForKey:languageChoosen] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]; which was causing all trouble.